# Windows.Interactivity, Microsoft.Expression.Interactions references are not found in Visual studio 2013 for a Wpf project

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

[image]

I've used the **System.Windows.Interactivity DLL** in several projects without any problem. Now in my latest project I can't get it to work. I always get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error before couple of months ago & what I did was, just open the Visual Studio installer again and selected "Modify". then Remove the ticks for the option Blend for Visual studio.

Comment: I want Blend for Visual studio to design the ui

Comment: In my case my project didn't related to blend. so I got it works. I will try to find out a solution